# ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous... comparision to None

Tags: python, numpy, opencv

I am beginner in Python with some background in C++ and Pascal. What I want to do is to load image with cv2 library and check if it was loaded properly:

```
filePathIn = 'E:\\test.jpg'
img = cv2.imread(filePathIn, cv2.IMREAD_COLOR )
if (img != None) :
    print (img.shape)
else:
    print ("Can't find file: "+filePathIn)
```

What I undestand is that `cv2.imread()` returns pointer to an object (which is a numpy array) and when no file was loaded it returns None.

So when the file is not found it works correctly and 'else' statement is executed. However if the file is actually loaded then I get this error, which I don't understand:

```
if (img != None):
```

> ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

I don't really care about elements of array, I just want to check if array exists.

Comment: `if img is not None:` would be be correct test.  It handles the `None` value correctly (equality tests on None are tricky), and won't give this error with an array.

Comment: Thx, it works. However, could you elaborate why equality tests on None are tricky? Especially while that statement is accepted by python when img is actually None (else statement in my code).

Comment: Oh, what I do think now is that: 'IS' is the identity comparison, which check is both arguments are the same instance <-> same adresses <->same pointers. So when it's used it checks if both: img and None are the same pointers.  However, when my image wasn't loaded then '==' operator ,which just compares values, compared None==None and it was just ok; however when my object had actual adress in memory than comparision img==None confused Python: which value of object img I should compare to None ?  Am I getting it right?

Comment: It's not equality tests with `None` that are tricky; it's equality tests with arrays.

Comment: `(id(img) != id(None)):` also works :)

Comment: `id` comparisons are a terrible way to test identity, because they can spuriously return `True` if the argument lifetimes don't overlap. That happens to not cause problems with `None`, since `None`'s lifetime is the whole program, but it's a terrible habit to get into nonetheless.

Comment: True ,but in this case I just want to check if object exists, not to compare identity. And it seems that method is totally safe, unless Python would start to switch reference to None constant in the middle of the program. Anyway it was just proof of concept of `IS` equivalent.

Comment: The object exists no matter what. It's impossible to run comparisons on an object that doesn't exist. An object being None is not the same as it not existing.

Answer (score 0):

"I just want to check if array exists"

then just say

```py
if img:
    print(img.shape)
```

Comment: "if img:" returns same error:     `if img :
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()`

Comment: I would try @hpaulj 's suggestion of using if img is None:, if that doesn't work you'll probably want to check the documentation on cv2.imread() to see what it returns in such a condition.

Answer (score -1):

Since `img` is a NumPy array with pixel values ranging from `[0, 255]`, you have to check for something else than using `np.all()` because some pixel values would be 0 and `np.all()` would return `False` in such cases.

To fix this error, replace the below line:

```
if (img != None) :
```

with the following line, which checks for non-nullity and the shape of the numpy array:

```
if img is not None and len(img.shape) > 0 :
```

---

Alternatively, you can use:

```
if np.all(img) is not None:
   # do more here
```

Note: The reason we check for `type()` of the object returned by `cv2.imread()` is because:

> The function imread loads an image from the specified file and returns it. If the image cannot be read (because of missing file, improper permissions, unsupported or invalid format), the function returns an empty matrix ( Mat::data==NULL ).

c.f. [reading_and_writing_images](https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/modules/imgcodecs/doc/reading_and_writing_images.html)

Comment: The first solution doesn't work if img was not loaded, because you check for shape of unexisting object `    print (len(img.shape) > 0) AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'shape' `

Comment: @JanK Thanks for pointing it out, I have updated the answer. Please have a look!